# How do i change date format to display month and year only using moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I would like to change this date time format using momentjs

```
2017-02-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

to

```
02-2017 ( month-year )
```

How to change this date format to get month-year only using momentjs?

I have tried like this:

```
var MnthYr = moment(2017-02-01T00:00:00.000Z).format("MM-YYYY");
```

but I didn't get exact answer

Comment: What is the type of your input? where do you get `2017-02-01T00:00:00.000Z`?

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Here a working sample:

```js
console.log( moment('2017-02-01T00:00:00.000Z').format('MM-YYYY') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the string by passing it into `moment()` and then display it in the right format using `.format()`, i.e.:

```
moment('2017-02-01T00:00:00.000Z').format('MM-YYYY')
```